# Como usar sprintf para montar uma query SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Qual a forma correta de usar `sprintf` no mysqli e fazer o IF de retorno?

```
$rs = $mysqli->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO perguntas (chave, nome, email, idade, estado_civil, profissao, religiao, assunto, pergunta, `data`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($chave),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['idade']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['estado_civil']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['profissao']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['religiao']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['assunto']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pergunta']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($data)));

    if (mysqli_query($rs)) {
        echo "<script>window.location = '".$baseURL."/enviar-aconselhamento&chave=$chave'</script>";
    }else{
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
```

Dessa forma que estou fazendo acima esta retornando erro:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , , , , , , , )' at line 1

Comment: Você está fazendo isso errado.

Comment: Essa é minha questão...rsrs, como fazer corretamente... Pode ajudar?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Pode ajudar?

Comment: Já consultou o manual do [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)?

Comment: Porque está fazendo sprintf?

Comment: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91), o `sprintf()` é uma otima solução para gera o template do sql e não para passar os valores em códigos legados ainda é aceitavel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu troquei o nome do seu campo de data do banco, pois a palavra "data" é uma variável reservada do MySQL, e não deve ser utilizada como nome de campo. Não é necessário utilizar a função `sprintf()`, O `mysqli` já tem a tratativa necessária, para valores através do `preparedStatment`:

```
$data = array(
              'chave' => mysqli_real_escape_string($chave),
              'nome'  => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']),
              'email' => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),
              'idade' => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['idade']),
              'estado_civil' => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['estado_civil']),
              'profissao' => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['profissao']),
              'religiao' => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['religiao']),
              'assunto' => mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['assunto']),
              'pergunta => 'mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pergunta']),
              'data_pub' => mysqli_real_escape_string($data_pub)
            );

$query = "INSERT INTO perguntas (`chave`,
                                 `nome`,
                                 `email`,
                                 `idade`,
                                 `estado_civil`,
                                 `profissao`,
                                 `religiao`,
                                 `assunto`,
                                 `pergunta`,
                                 `data_pub`)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt ->bind_param("ssssssssss", $data['chave'],$data['nome'],$data['email'],$data['idade'],$data['estado_civil'],$data['profissao'],$data['religiao'],$data['assunto'],$data['pergunta'],$data['data_pub']);
$action = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
if ($action) {
   echo "<script>window.location.href='{$baseURL}/enviar-aconselhamento&chave={$chave}'</script>";
} else {
  die('Erro: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Comment: Não precisava trocar o nome da coluna. Pode ser usado o nome "data".  Para evitar conflito com nomes reservados, escapa-se com backsticks `data`. Aliás, no código original da pergunta já está escapado.

Comment: Esta sua solução não é a melhor maneira de contornar o problema, eu prefiro resolver o problema na raiz a ter que tratar todo o dado que será usado evitando novos conflitos. O melhor é sempre otimizar a arquitetura.

Comment: Isso não é "a minha solução". É um recurso básico do MySQL. Nada tem a ver com otimizar estrutura e nada ver com isso que disse.

Comment: Eu costumo utilizar um padrão de indexação: `created_at`

Comment: Eu também faço justamente pelo mesmo motivo, para evitar conflito de nomes reservados e também porque não gosto de usar os backsticks.. Mas não é o caso aqui e tampouco é o foco do assunto, sacou? Desnecessário modificar a estrutura alheia. Era só mostrar o uso do sprintf() e pimba! rsrs

Comment: Não precisa de `sprintf()` para o problema apresentado, então não tem porque mostrar o uso dele, e mesmo que o assunto seja fora do foco, eu procuro orientar as pessoas da melhor maneira possível, não se trata de resolver apenas o problema, não vejo porque ocultar uma informação que só tem a somar soluções.

Comment: O foco da pergunta é sobre sprintf().. agora o conceito do que é certo ou errado não tem nada a ver.. conceito é conceito.. Ninguém é obrigado a usar OOP, PDO, uma função X ou Y para resolver um problema que pode  ser resolvido de N formas... Mas enfim... não está errado o que postou.. Apenas perguntei o porque modificar o nome da coluna.. sem necessidade.. só isso..

Comment: A pergunta em si é sobre o uso do `sprintf()`, mas se você notar no detalhe da pergunta, a dúvida do colega Tiago leva para um outro sentido em sua dúvida, o qual sugere uma resposta mais relevante ao problema apresentado.

Comment: E nenhum momento eu citei que você é obrigado usar OOP ou PDO, ou uma função X ou Y para resolver um problema, e também não existe um certo ou errado para discutir aqui, nem vejo necessidade disso. O que coloco aqui é apenas uma sugestão para seguir boas práticas, como é disposto nas [PSRs](http://www.php-fig.org/), se você prefere manifestar oposição à isso, você é livre para isso.

Comment: Não tem nada a ver.. Ivan.. é improdutivo ficarmos aqui discutindo e vc parece não interpretar direito o que eu coloco e até "meio" que distorcendo o sentido do que comentei... Enfim, por mim, o assunto estava já encerrado. Não sou de ignorar alguem deixando uma discussão em aberto, mas não dá para conversar contigo, pois vc distorce o que eu coloco.. desculpe.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33828/discussion-between-ivan-ferrer-and-daniel-omine).

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, `sprintf()` não tem relação com `mysqli()`.

Vamos direto ao ponto.

Nesse trecho:

```
$rs = $mysqli->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO perguntas (chave, nome, email, idade, estado_civil, profissao, religiao, assunto, pergunta, `data`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($chave),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['idade']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['estado_civil']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['profissao']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['religiao']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['assunto']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pergunta']),
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($data)));
```

Substitua por isso:

```
$columns = array('chave', 'nome', 'email', 'idade', 'estado_civil', 'profissao', 'religiao', 'assunto', 'pergunta', 'data');
$parameters = array($chave, 'nome', 'email', 'idade', 'estado_civil', 'profissao', 'religiao', 'assunto', 'pergunta', 'data');
$values[] = $chave;
foreach ($parameters as $k => $v)
    $values[] = (isset($_POST[$v])? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[$v]) : '');
$values[] = $data;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO table ('.vsprintf("`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`,`%s`", $columns).')
 VALUES ('.vsprintf("'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'", $values).')';

$rs = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Utilizei [vsprintf()](http://php.net/vsprintf) ao invés de [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) porque [vsprintf()](http://php.net/vsprintf) suporta array no segundo parâmetro. Isso facilita adicionar parâmetros dinamicamente.